# Pagination with node-themoviedb

Tags: node.js, parameters, pagination

My question is probably very simple, or the answer on it is. I'm doing some project of mine, non-profitable, movie/show tracking type web application. I'm using TMDb API, and in node I'm using node-themoviedb wrapper. Can I, somehow pass the parameters to the wrapper to which page I want from the API. Now I know, API can through URL parameters, know which page I want, but I'm asking for this wrapper. Should I even do pagination in backend, or is it simpler doing it in frontend? Thanks!